# Shared Excel macro enabled workbook - Excel cannot access the file issue

Tags: vba, excel

**What I want to do.**

Send my Macro enabled Excel document to my colleagues with a working macro that opens a save file dialog and then generates this csv.

**What have I done?**

I have made a VBA-macro in Excel 2013 and it works fine on my machine. However, when I send this Macro enabled excel-sheet to my colleague he gets:

Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'Path to the document on MY computer'. There are several possible reasons:

- The file name or path does not exist.
- The file is being used by another program.
- The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook

My Source:

```
Sub Convert2CSV()
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = "OrderSedel_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh mm") & ".csv"

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
            .Title = "xxx"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .InitialFileName = fileName
            .FilterIndex = 15
            result = .Show
            If (result <> 0) Then
                ' create file
                fileName = Trim(.SelectedItems.Item(1))
                fnum = FreeFile
                Open fileName For Output As fnum


                ' Write the csv data from form record set
                For i = 7 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                    If ( _
                        (Not Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString Or _
                        Not Trim(Cells(i, 3).Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString) And _
                        Not Trim(Cells(i, 9).Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString) Then
                            'Check EAN (Trim). If No EAN get Bolist ArtNum
                            If (Trim(Cells(i, 3).Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString) Then
                                Print #fnum, Cells(i, 1).Value & ";" & Cells(i, 9).Value
                                Else
                                Print #fnum, Cells(i, 3).Value & ";" & Cells(i, 9).Value
                                End If
                    End If
                Next i



            ' close file
            Close #fnum
            End If
      End With

End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of file xlsm]

Comment: Is it possible that he can press "Debug" after the error pops up? And see what line is causing an error?

Comment: @BranislavKollár No :(

Comment: The *" 'Path to the document on MY computer' "* can be interpreted as *" 'Path to the document on Joakim M computer' "*?

Comment: @BranislavKollár Yes :)

Comment: Are you being serious?

Comment: @user3819867 What's not to be serious about?

Comment: Does given user have access to your folder?

Comment: I have faced a similar issue though when I tried to run a macro written in MS *Excel 2010* on a PC with *Excel 2007*.

Comment: @user3819867 I am not sharing the document. I am sending the document to him via mail. My macro is in no way depending on my computer's folders. Or shouldn't be anyhow. That is why I am so confused about the error message.

Comment: I don't have 2013 to test on, but can you browse the properties of `.FileDialog` to see if there's a Default Directory property that you could set? It could be that the default directory is somehow 'stuck' on a path on _your_ machine, and if you set it to something like `%My Documents%` in your code, it may resolve that at run-time and pick up your coworker's `MyDocuments` instead of trying to access yours.

Comment: In re: my comment above, try setting `.InitialFileName` "Set or returns a String representing the _path_ or file name that is initially displayed in a file dialog box.". Took me a minute to find it in the [MS Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff863983.aspx)

Comment: I am setting InitialFileName :(

Comment: This error can be non-macro issue. Do you have some data links (normal Excel feature, Data - connections) in the workbook? Some formulas using specified paths, some other connections to tables? [Ilustration of what I mean](http://docs.deltadna.com/dd-content/uploads/2014/08/connections.jpg)

Comment: Btw, there is no such thing as **Macro enabled Excel document**. The macro security settings are application dependent (each user has his own). So if your collegue wants to use the macro, he needs to allow it (either by clicking one time popup "Enable content" or something like that on every workbook opening, or the application settings). But I'm sure you have this covered.

Comment: @BranislavKollár The correct name should be Excel macro-enabled workbook (see my attached image). Sorry about that.

Comment: Ou, that was a bit stupid from my side. I forgot that the xlsm files are defined like that. *Me, Nooob*. But please, see my preceding comment, about the non-macro issue. What do you think about that?

Comment: @BranislavKollár Looking into it. And I will probably be placed in the Noob-compartment myself...

Comment: @BranislavKollár Calling the same macro from a button inside the sheet fixed (avoided is the correct word) the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Send the code for them to insert into a macro to run it and see if they get the same error. It ran fine for me (except that I define my variables).

It could be that their copy of Excel is not set up to trust VBA. (Under Settings.)